# _GADAdSizeFromCGSize", referenced from:

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

I just integrated adwhirl to my code and I started receiving this error.

```
_GADAdSizeFromCGSize", referenced from: 
_GADAdSizeFromCGSize", referenced from: -[AdWhirlAdapterGoogleAdMobAds getAd] in AdWhirlAdapterGoogleAdMobAds.o
```

What could be the possible reason. I have added the possible frameworks.

[image: Frameworks added]

Comment: Tried to answer a similar ticket. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825052/error-while-integrating-admob-in-iphone-app/12271530#12271530