# Error while integrating admob in iPhone app

Tags: ios, admob

"_GADAdSizeFromCGSize",referenced from:
-[AdWhirlAdapterGoogleAdMobAds getAd] in AdWhirlAdapterGoogleAdMobAds.o
Symbols not found for architecture armv7

Linker command failed with exit code 1(use -v to see invocation)

Please help me..not able to find why is it showing?and I have added all the frameworks needed but still it's showing this error.

I am following this tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2011/11/24/how-to-integrate-adwhirl-into-a-cocos2d-game/

Comment: https://www.adwhirl.com/doc/ios/AdWhirliOSSDKSetup.html 
Check this link,may be you forgot to add any frameworks.

Comment: I have added all the needed frameworks..still ..not able to get whats wrong.. :(

Comment: You are missing the libGoogleAdMobAds.a from link libraries.Try it out !!

Comment: I am only getting iAd,when iAd is not appearing it should show admob ads(google ads?)but its showing blank instead..hat can be reason?

Comment: Are you sure you're not referring to an old version of the SDK in your "Library Search Paths" under your Build Settings?

Comment: Ok thanks everyone,Problem solved as if there was no problem..I mean successfully integrated iAd and admob...May be it is taking time to display ads after integrating admob in project..All of sudden I got the ads in my app after spending 5-6 hours on testing again n again..Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you add libGoogleAdMobAds.a to your linked frameworks and that you add -all_load to your Other Linker Flags section in your Build Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Faced this issue while adding a new `Google AdMob SDK` to an existing project with older SDK.

For some reason, the new SDK was added to the '`Library Search Paths`' along with the older one. So, from `Build Settings`, remove un-necessary AdMod SDK `Library Search Paths` and you are good to go.

Also add `-all_load` to 'Other Linker Flags' to avoid another `[GADBannerView private]: unrecognized selector` crash.